# Convert 1D Array to 2D Array and append Array to last Row of Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, compare, difference

I am having 2 array lists from which i am finding the difference.

```js
arr1 = ['Sam','Annie', 'Margorie', 'Ester', 'John'];
arr2 = ['Bill', 'Sally', 'Sam', 'Annie', 'Suman', 'Margorie', 'Ester', 'Pierre', 'John'];

var diff = arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x));

console.log(diff) //result....diff = ['Bill', 'Sally', 'Suman', 'Pierre']
```

What i want to do is to modify the above Filter Arrow function to add 'New' for each item' so that the resultant array becomes:

```
//diff = [['Bill', 'New'] , ['Sally', 'New'] , ['Suman', 'New'] , ['Pierre' , 'New']]
```

I can do this separately using a Map Arrow function like this:

```
diff = diff.map(x => [x,'New']);
```

- But i want to club both these functions together. Is that possible?
- Also, when i try to append this array to the last row of the sheet, the last row shows 'Object@xxx' instead of the actual values.

e.g.

```
Sht.appendRow(diff);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine map/filter, Use a simple for-loop/if or reduce:

```js
arr1 = ['Sam','Annie', 'Margorie', 'Ester', 'John'];
arr2 = ['Bill', 'Sally', 'Sam', 'Annie', 'Suman', 'Margorie', 'Ester', 'Pierre', 'John'];

const diff = arr2.reduce((diff,x) => !arr1.includes(x) ? [...diff , [x, "New"]] : diff, [] );

console.log(diff) //result....diff = ['Bill', 'Sally', 'Suman', 'Pierre']
```

[Sheet#appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) only accepts a 1D(1-dimensional) array. Use `range.setValues()`  if you want to append a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks. Just on a side note, can this be rewritten as normal javascript instead of using Arrow functions? I am still grappling with Arrow functions.

Comment: @sifar `const diff = arr2.reduce(function(diff,x) { return !arr1.includes(x) ? [...diff , [x, "New"]] : diff}, [] );` or more elaborately `const diff = arr2.reduce(function(diff,x) { if (!arr1.includes(x))return diff.concat([x, "New"]); return diff}, [] );`

Comment: Excellent! But is there a reason for using `Const` instead of `Var`? And from a speed performance perspective, which should be faster for large ranges?

Comment: @sifar `const` or `let` is preferable due to scope restrictions and therefore less error-prone. `var` should generally be avoided.  [JavaScript tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) has   excellent resources.